# How to extact specific information from the exif data and display it in our Web page/

Tags: javascript, exif

I am using the exif.js from [here](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js).
I have currently extracted all the data from my img with `EXIF.getData()`, and have displayed it in my  as a side to the picture.

But now I want to display not all the data, but to specify what exactly (camera model, date when the picture was taken, if there are any Tags to the picture, etc).

My pictures are I JSON file and I have added Tags to all of them. 
I am not sure how to approach it. Should I use EXIF.getData() and proceed somehow from there? I am extracting the data on IMG click in a modal dialog.

```js
     function clickImage(){
        let images = $(".box img");
        images.click(function() {
            modalContent.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            modalView.css('display', 'block');
            googleMap.css('display','none');

             EXIF.getData(this, function() {
               result.text(EXIF.pretty(this))
          }          
     }
```

Currently, I gave all the date in `result`.

Comment: So far i have made it like this :

Answer (score 0):

You should use [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) instead of exif-js because it has been unmaintained for two years and still has breaking bugs in it (n is undefined).

With exifr you can either parse everything

```js
exifr.parse('./myimage.jpg').then(output => {
  console.log('Camera:', output.Make, output.Model))
})
```

or just a few tags

```js
let output = await exifr.parse(file, ['ISO', 'Orientation', 'LensModel'])
```